# Excel VBA XPath expression error - Expected token ')' found ':'

Tags: xml, excel, vba, xpath

Currently I'm in the process of retrieving some data from XML document inside a Excel VBA code using a Xpath expression. My goal is to retrieve unique ids from the XML. Here is the xpath expression I tried.

```
//u:UserID[not(. = following::u:UserID/.)]
```

I tried the Xpath using Notepad++ xml plugin and it works perfectly. However this does not work with MSXML documents in MS-EXCEL VBA and throws following error.

```
Expected token ')' found ':'.
```

According to [Martin Honnen](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/martin%20honnen/?ws=usercard-mini) described in [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fa61c611-2199-46e6-a555-25ec81c77c99/expected-token-found-existsindexof-15-40-25-40-10-40?forum=xmlandnetfx&prof=required) this is because of XPath 2.0 features doesn't support in Microsoft XSLT processors.

Can someone kindly guide me on how to convert above Xpath expression From XPath 2.0 to XPath 1.0?

Thanks in advance,
Prasaz

Please find the sample code below.

Sample XML:

```
<u:root name="user" xmlns:u="http://example.com/user">
<u:Transactions>
    <u:Transaction>
        <u:TransactionID>1</u:TransactionID>
        <u:FUser>
            <u:UserTypeID>270</u:UserTypeID>
            <u:UserID>67</u:UserID>
            <u:Username>User67</u:Username>
        </u:FUser>
        <u:TUser>
            <u:UserTypeID>202</u:UserTypeID>
            <u:UserID>16</u:UserID>
            <u:Username>User16</u:Username>
        </u:TUser>
    </u:Transaction>
    <u:Transaction>
        <u:TransactionID>2</u:TransactionID>
        <u:FUser>
            <u:UserTypeID>267</u:UserTypeID>
            <u:UserID>64</u:UserID>
            <u:Username>User64</u:Username>
        </u:FUser>
        <u:TUser>
            <u:UserTypeID>202</u:UserTypeID>
            <u:UserID>16</u:UserID>
            <u:Username>User16</u:Username>
        </u:TUser>
    </u:Transaction>
</u:Transactions>
```

Sample VBA

```
Private userXMLDocument As DOMDocument
Set userXMLDocument= New DOMDocument

// Code loading data data to the userXMLDocument
// Once done,

Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
//Next line generates the error
Set xmlNodeList = userXMLDocument.SelectNodes("//u:UserID[not(.= following::u:UserID/.)]")
```

Comment: Your XPath doesn't seems to use XPath 2.0 specific features, I suspect this is just a problem of using namespace prefix (`u:`). Maybe posting some relevant VBA codes around this XPath can help us to diagnose the problem further

Comment: The path expression is fine in XPath 1.0. Can you post your code?

Comment: It may be that the XPath engine in VBA doesn't recognize the `following::` axis. That would kinda surprise me, but see if it still shows an error if you remove the `following::` part.

Comment: Are you setting the `selectionNamespaces` in the document at any point? Again, I'd be surprised if not having them would cause this particular error, but it's worth looking into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you help.

Finally manage to sort it out. The issue was with the userXMLDocument objects selection language property. it was set to `XSLPattern` instead of `XPATH` once I set it to `XPATH` i had a another issue where it didn't recognize the namespace prefix (`u:`). Then as mentioned by [JLRishe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1945651/jlrishe) all I needed to pass the proper namespace using the `selectionNamespaces` property.

Please see below the code for your reference

```
Private userXMLDocument As DOMDocument
Set userXMLDocument= New DOMDocument
Dim xmlNameSpaces As String

xmlNameSpaces = "valid xml namespace"
userXMLDocument.LoadXML(xmlFilePath)

userXMLDocument.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
userXMLDocument.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", xmlNameSpaces

Dim xmlNodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList

Set xmlNodeList = userXMLDocument.SelectNodes("//u:UserID[not(. = following::u:UserID/.)]")
MsgBox xmlNodeList.Length, vbInformation, "Node Count"
```